# Add a User to Teams groups by .CSV

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams, usergroups

I'm trying to make a simple Powershell script to add a user to few groups determined by .csv file for new users and stuff.
I took for help this article : https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2021/08/bulk-add-users-to-microsoft-teams-using-powershell.html?

I may be mistaking with .csv/ForEach/Try all together.

The error I get is "-GroupID" in Add-TeamUser gets a "null" so it won't work.
Replacing "$GrpName" to an actual group name in the Get-Team command works.
So the problem must be the .csv reading... I guess.'

```
\#Connect Microsoft Teams
Connect-MicrosoftTeams

\#Select .csv with browsing
$FileBrowser = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog -Property @{
InitialDirectory = \[Environment\]::GetFolderPath('Desktop')
Filter = "CSV (\*.csv) | \*.csv"
}
$null = $FileBrowser.ShowDialog()
$CSVPath = $FileBrowser.FileName
$inputHeaders = 'Group', 'Role'

\#Select User name
$UserTeams = Read-Host "Name of User"

\#Import Groups by .csv
$Import = Import-Csv -Path $CSVPath -Delimiter ";" -Header $inputHeaders| ForEach-Object {

\#Transform group name into group ID
$GrpName = $Import.Group
$TeamID = Get-Team | Where {$\_.DisplayName -eq $GrpName} | Select -ExpandProperty GroupID
$Role = $Import.Role

\#Add User to the Groups
Add-TeamUser -GroupId $TeamID -User $UserTeams -Role $Role
}
```

Comment: To debug issue use : $import | Format-Table which will display all the columns and names.  Than you can check to see if the reading of the CSV is correct.

Comment: I got a glitch using the "-Header $InputHeaders" but getting rid of it, the .csv is well-behaving with my 2 columns (Group and Role), but the bug remains :/

Comment: Use Format-Table with $TeamID : $TeamID | Format-Table  See if it contains GroupId

Comment: You are looping over the **collection** in $import with ForEach-Object, so you should change `$GrpName = $Import.Group` into `$GrpName = $_.Group` and `$Role = $Import.Role` into `$Role = $_.Role` inside the loop

Comment: Thank you jdweng and @Theo, works fine with "$_." (just 1 residual error message) but the Add-Team is Ope.
Hope my mistakes can help some other people :)
Have a nice day!
For people who would use it : Get rid of "\". I messed up somehow with StackOverflow editing rules.